# How to add something like a virtual billboard in a video with python

Tags: python, opencv, mask, homography

Virtual billboard is commonly used in sports broadcasting. These billboards is not real and will covered by the moving objects in front of them just like it's right there. I'm wondering is it possible to do this via python? Take [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqctLW0Hb_0&feature=youtu.be) as an example. (you can download it through [this](https://qdownloader.net/youtube-video-downloader).) Can we add something above the lane but below the vehicles? Let's say this simple yellow rectangle:

[image]

Add it to a lane will be something like this:

[image]

And when the vehicles passed this yellow area, the area should be covered by the vehicles rather than cover the vehicle.

Before dealing with video, what I'm trying is first using homography and some wrapping to add the rectangle onto and fit the lane area in a picture with the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# source image
source_img = cv2.imread('yellow_rec.jpg')
size = source_img.shape
# get four corners of the source (clock wise)
pts_source = np.array(
                    [
                    [0,0],
                    [size[1] - 1, 0],
                    [size[1] - 1, size[0] -1],
                    [0, size[0] - 1 ]
                    ],dtype=float
                    )
#pts_source = np.array([[310,0], [440,0], [589,151],[383,151]])

# destination image
dst_img = cv2.imread('video_screen_shot.png')
# four corners in destination image (also clock wise):
pts_dst = np.array([[400,115], [531,108], [647,186],[533,244]])

# calculate homography
h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_source, pts_dst)

# warp source image to destination based on homography
temp = cv2.warpPerspective(source_img, h, (dst_img.shape[1], dst_img.shape[0]))

# Black out polygonal area in destination image.
cv2.fillConvexPoly(dst_img, pts_dst.astype(int), 0, 16)

# Add warped source image to destination image.
dst_img = dst_img + temp

cv2.imshow('warpped', dst_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Which gives me:[image]

However, if I do this on every video frame, the yellow area will just cover the vehicles passing it rather than being coverred by the vehicles. How could I make it like a virtual billboard, which will be covered by the moving objects in the video?

Comment: This is waaaaay too broad for stack overflow

Comment: But in general what you're talking about is a first and ten system.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_%26_Ten_(graphics_system)#Conception